# Detecting python serial read timeout or serial interruption

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am making a program to talk to a piece of serial equipment. The code I have so far allows me to talk to the device just fine. However I would like to have the program do alert the user if the link does dead, along with triggering a different section of code. Ideally I would like the code to be able to detect a interruption in any part in the transmission.

I intend to have this code used with kivy with a user interface to indicate link status.

I have read about people using threading, and I have tried making timers with threading. But I think it all just gets messy.

Thank you for any input.

```
import serial
import time

# lineread is the variable to store the data read from comport
#    b"\x80"   is the format to read and write hex values   this = 80 in hex

SerialConfig = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, timeout=.1) # comport configurations

def Start_loop():
    while True: # loop forever
        lineread = SerialConfig.read() # lineread variable is = to serial configurations reading from com port

        if lineread == b"\x80": # wait for device to start handshake
            SerialConfig.write(b"\x80") # reply to device with handshake
            del lineread # clear lineread variable to wait for next value to come in

            while True: # keep looping till
                lineread = SerialConfig.read()  # lineread variable is = to serial configurations reading from com port
                if lineread == b"\x80": # if comport sees reply respond with the following lines
                    SerialConfig.write(b"\xA0")
                    SerialConfig.write(b"\x90")
                    print("handshake complete")
```

Comment: The common solution is to either use a HW scheme such as monitoring a modem handshake line such as data carrier detect (DCD), or a software scheme such as a periodic poll (and expecting an "I'm alive" response in a timely manner).  IMO the SW scheme can be the most reliable, as it covers more than just a physical disconnection.

Comment: Your code has variable names and multiple comments that mention *"lines"* that do not seem to have any EOL character.  Do not conflate a *"line"* with a datagram, packet, or message.  Various system calls and I/O routines will enforce EOL detection for reading/handling *"lines"*.  BTW specifying parity is essentially useless, and is high overhead (i.e. wastes 10% bandwidth).  Far better to ensure/validate message integrity with a CRC.

Comment: My intent is to have the code know when the connection is lost even while waiting for a returned command "datagram, packet, or message" I don't want my program to get hung up waiting for something that may not happen. You have to keep in mind that the box that I am trying to talk to is a black box that I did not design. The parity bit is out of my control I did not design the black box I just found that was what it accepts.